# How can I run concurrent requests in Python FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, fastapi, uvicorn

I want to run multiple requests in concurrency in Python FastAPI, my current py file `script.py` is as follows:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import time

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def func(text: str):
    time.sleep(5)
    return {'text': text}
```

I run the API using `uvicorn script:app --reload` and calling the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?text=test`

When making 3 requests at the same time to this endpoint, I get the 1st response in 5 seconds, the 2nd response in 10 seconds, and the 3rd in 15 seconds.

How can I run the 3 requests in parallel to return them all in 5 seconds?

Comment: Try with `asyncio.sleep(5)`. To support concurrency, your endpoint must support async operations, and the standard `time.sleep` is a blocking operation.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)