# FastAPI runs api-calls in serial instead of parallel fashion

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi, concurrent-processing

I have the following code:

```py
import time
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
    
app = FastAPI()
    
@app.get("/ping")
async def ping(request: Request):
        print("Hello")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("bye")
        return {"ping": "pong!"}
```

If I run my code on localhost - e.g., `http://localhost:8501/ping` - in different tabs of the same browser window, I get:

```
Hello
bye
Hello
bye
```

instead of:

```
Hello
Hello
bye
bye
```

I have read about using `httpx`, but still, I cannot have a true parallelization. What's the problem?

Comment: Did the accepted answer help you?  I still have same behaviour as your question.  With a single worker, all requests (sync or async) *always* run serial, instead of parallel.

Comment: I have never set the amount of workers to use with uvicorn to be honest... Could it be that? Without defining it, to me they are working parallel without async. At least with version fastapi=0.85.0

Comment: Chrome at least, blocks concurrent GET reuqests on the same URL (probably to get a chance to use the chached versin on the next one?) 

Testing with one Chrome in Incognito should work, with "def" as well as with "async def".

Comment: In short, replace `time.sleep()` with `await asyncio.sleep()`, then you will get concurrency.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

As per [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#path-operation-functions):

> When you declare a path operation function with normal `def` instead
> of `async def`, it is run in an external threadpool that is then
> `await`ed, **instead of being called directly** (as it **would block the
> server**).

also, as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#concurrency-and-async-await):

> If you are using a third party library that communicates with
> something (a database, an API, the file system, etc.) and doesn't have
> support for using `await`, (this is currently the case for most
> database libraries), then declare your path operation functions as
> normally, with just `def`.
>
> If your application (somehow) doesn't have to communicate with
> anything else and wait for it to respond, use `async def`.
>
> If you just don't know, use normal `def`.
>
> **Note**: You can mix `def` and `async def` in your path operation functions as much as you need and define each one using the best
> option for you. FastAPI will do the right thing with them.
>
> Anyway, in any of the cases above, FastAPI **will still work
> asynchronously** and be extremely fast.
>
> But by following the steps above, it will be able to do some
> performance optimizations.

Thus, in order to avoid blocking the server, `def` endpoints—in the context of asynchronous programming, a function defined with just `def` is called *synchronous* function—in FastAPI, will run in a separate thread from an external threadpool **that is then `await`ed** (more details on the external threadpool are given later on), and hence, FastAPI will still work *asynchronously*. In other words, the server will process requests to such endpoints *concurrently* (but will spawn a new thread for every incoming request). Whereas, `async def` endpoints run *directly* in the [`event loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html)—which runs in the main (single) thread, and is created when calling, for instance, [`uvicorn.run()`](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/a05ae6426cc8f224f4f1a995f46a901ab0f5644b/uvicorn/server.py#L60), or the equivalent method of some [other ASGI server](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/manually/)—that is, the server **will also** process requests to such endpoints *concurrently*/*asynchronously*, **as long as there is** an [`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865050/is-await-in-python3-cooperative-multitasking) call to non-blocking I/O-bound operations inside such `async def` endpoints/routes, such as *waiting* for (1) data from the client to be sent through the network, (2) contents of a file in the disk to be read, (3) a database operation to finish, etc., (have a look [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#asynchronous-code)).

**However**, if an endpoint defined with `async def` does not `await` for some [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) inside (i.e., a coroutine object is the result of calling an `async def` function), in order to give up time for other tasks in the `event loop` to run (e.g., requests to the same or other endpoints, background tasks, etc.), each request to such an endpoint will have to be completely finished (i.e., exit the endpoint), before returning control back to the `event loop` and allowing other tasks in the `event loop` to run (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78155528/17865804), if you would like to get and monitor all pending tasks in an `event loop`). In other words, in such cases, the server would be "blocked" and have to process requests *sequentially*. Having said that, you should still define an endpoint with `async def`, if your endpoint **does not** have to execute a blocking operation inside and wait for it to respond, but is instead used to simply [return JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804), `FileResponse`, `HTMLResponse`, etc., even if there is not an `await` statement inside the endpoint in such cases, as FastAPI would likely perform better when running such a simple endpoint *directly* in the event loop, rather than spawning a new thread from the external threadpool (in case the endpoint was instead defined with normal `def`).

**Note** that the same concept not only applies to endpoints, but also to functions that are used as [`StreamingResponse`'s generators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) (see [`StreamingResponse`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/31164e346b9bd1ce17d968e1301c3bb2c23bb418/starlette/responses.py#L235) class implementation) or [`Background Tasks`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) (see [`BackgroundTask`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/33f46a13625bcca4b7520e33be299a23b2e2b26c/starlette/background.py#L15) class implementation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804)), meaning that FastAPI, behind the scenes, **will also** run such functions defined with normal `def` in a separate thread from the **same** external threadpool; whereas, if such functions were defined with `async def` instead, they would run directly in the `event loop`. In order to run an endpoint or a function described above in a separate thread and `await` it, FastAPI uses Starlette's asynchronous [`run_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/concurrency.py#L35) function, which, under the hood, calls [`anyio.to_thread.run_sync()`](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#anyio.to_thread.run_sync). The default number of worker threads of that external threadpool is `40` and can be adjusted as required—please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) for more details on the external threadpool and how to adjust the number of threads. Hence, after reading this answer to the end, you should be able to decide whether you should define a FastAPI endpoint, `StreamingResponse`'s generator or `BackgroundTask` function with `def` or `async def`.

#### Python's `async def` function and `await`

The keyword `await` (which only works within an `async def` function) passes function control back to the `event loop`. In other words, it suspends the execution of the surrounding coroutine, and tells the `event loop` to let some other task run, until that `await`ed task is completed. **Note** that just because you may define a custom function with `async def` and then `await` it inside your `async def` endpoint, it doesn't mean that your code will work asynchronously, if that custom function contains, for example, calls to [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), CPU-bound tasks, non-async I/O libraries, or any other blocking call that is incompatible with asynchronous Python code. In FastAPI, for example, when using the `async` methods of [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile), such as `await file.read()` and `await file.write()`, FastAPI/Starlette, behind the scenes, actually calls the corresponding *synchronous* [File methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in a separate thread from the external threadpool described earlier (using `run_in_threadpool()`) and `await`s it; otherwise, such methods/operations would block the `event loop`—you could find out more by looking at the [implementation of the `UploadFile` class](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/048643adc21e75b668567fc6bcdd3650b89044ea/starlette/datastructures.py#L426).

**Note**  that `async` does not mean *parallel*, but *concurrently*. As mentioned earlier, asynchronous code with [`async` and `await` is many times summarised as using *coroutines*](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#coroutines). Coroutines are collaborative (or [cooperatively multitasked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking)), meaning that "at any given time, a program with coroutines is running **only** one of its coroutines, and this running coroutine suspends its execution only when it explicitly requests to be suspended" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553704/what-is-a-coroutine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934715/difference-between-a-coroutine-and-a-thread) for more info on coroutines).

As described in [this article](https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/pyasync-fundam/):

> Specifically, whenever execution of a currently-running coroutine
> reaches an `await` expression, the coroutine may be suspended, and
> another previously-suspended coroutine may resume execution if what it
> was suspended on has since returned a value. Suspension can also
> happen when an `async for` block requests the next value from an
> asynchronous iterator or when an `async with` block is entered or
> exited, as these operations use `await` under the hood.

If, however, a blocking I/O-bound or CPU-bound operation was *directly* executed/called inside an `async def` function/endpoint, it would then **block the event loop**, and hence, the main thread would be blocked as well (the `event loop` runs in the main thread of a process/worker). Hence, a blocking operation such as `time.sleep()` in an `async def` endpoint would block the entire server (as in the code example provided in your question). Thus, if your endpoint is not going to make any `async` calls, you could declare it with normal `def` instead, in which case, FastAPI would run it in a separate thread from the external threadpool and `await` it, as explained earlier (more solutions are given in the following sections). Example:

```py
@app.get("/ping")
def ping(request: Request):
    #print(request.client)
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("bye")
    return "pong"
```

Otherwise, if the functions that you had to execute inside the endpoint are `async` functions that you had to `await`, you should define your endpoint with `async def`. To demonstrate this, the example below uses the [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) function (from the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library), which provides a **non-blocking** sleep operation. The `await asyncio.sleep()` method will suspend the execution of the surrounding coroutine (until the sleep operation is completed), thus allowing other tasks in the `event loop` to run. Similar examples are given [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730924) as well.

```py
import asyncio
 
@app.get("/ping")
async def ping(request: Request):
    #print(request.client)
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("bye")
    return "pong"
```

**Both** the endpoints above will print out the specified messages to the screen in the same order as mentioned in your question—if two requests arrived at (around) the same time—that is:

```
Hello
Hello
bye
bye
```

#### Important Note

When using a browser to call the same endpoint for the second (third, and so on) time, please remember to do that **from a tab that is isolated from the browser's main session**; otherwise, succeeding requests (i.e., coming after the first one) might be **blocked** by the browser (on **client side**), as the browser might be waiting for a response to the previous request from the server, before sending the next request. This is a common behaviour for Chrome browser at least, due to waiting to see the result of a request and check if the result can be cached, before requesting the same resource again.

You could confirm that by using `print(request.client)` inside the endpoint, where you would see the `hostname` and `port` number being the same for all incoming requests—in case the requests were initiated from tabs opened in the same browser window/session; otherwise, the `port` number would normally be different for every request—and hence, those requests would be processed sequentially by the server, because of the browser/client sending them sequentially in the first place. To **overcome** this, you could either:

1. Reload the same tab (as is running), or
2. Open a new tab in an Incognito Window, or
3. Use a different browser/client to send the request, or
4. Use the `httpx` library to [make asynchronous HTTP requests](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#making-async-requests), along with the [*awaitable*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) [`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), which allows executing multiple asynchronous operations concurrently and then returns a list of results in the **same** order the awaitables (tasks) were passed to that function (have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) for more details).

   **Example**:

   ```py
   import httpx
   import asyncio

   URLS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000/ping'] * 2

   async def send(url, client):
       return await client.get(url, timeout=10)

   async def main():
       async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
           tasks = [send(url, client) for url in URLS]
           responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           print(*[r.json() for r in responses], sep='\n')

   asyncio.run(main())
   ```

   In case you had to call different endpoints that may take different time to process a request, and you would like to print the response out on client side as soon as it is returned from the server—instead of waiting for `asyncio.gather()` to gather the results of all tasks and print them out in the same order the tasks were passed to the `send()` function—you could replace the `send()` function of the example above with the one shown below:

   ```
   async def send(url, client):
       res = await client.get(url, timeout=10)
       print(res.json())
       return res
   ```

### `Async`/`await` and Blocking I/O-bound or CPU-bound Operations

If you are required to define a FastAPI endpoint (or a `StreamingResponse`'s generator, or a background task function)  with `async def` (as you might need to `await` for some coroutines inside it), but also have some *synchronous* blocking I/O-bound or CPU-bound operation (computationally intensive task) that would block the `event loop` (essentially, the entire server) and wouldn't let other requests to go through, for example:

```py
@app.post("/ping")
async def ping(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print("Hello")
    try:
        contents = await file.read()
        res = cpu_bound_task(contents)  # this would block the event loop
    finally:
        await file.close()
    print("bye")
    return "pong"
```

then:

1. You should check whether you could change your endpoint's definition to normal `def` instead of `async def`. For example, if the only method in your endpoint that has to be awaited is the one reading the file contents (as you mentioned in the comments section below), you could instead declare the type of the endpoint's parameter as `bytes` (i.e., `file: bytes = File()`) and thus, FastAPI would read the file for you and you would receive the contents as `bytes`. Hence, there would be no need to use `await file.read()`. Please note that the above approach should work for small files, as the enitre file contents would be stored into memory (see the [documentation on `File` Parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#define-file-parameters)); and hence, if your system does not have enough RAM available to accommodate the accumulated data (if, for example, you have 8GB of RAM, you can’t load a 50GB file), your application may end up crashing. Alternatively, you could call the `.read()` method of the [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) directly (which can be accessed through the `.file` attribute of the `UploadFile` object), so that again you don't have to `await` the `.read()` method—and as you can now declare your endpoint with normal `def`, each request will run in a **separate thread** (example is given below). For more details on how to upload a `File`, as well how Starlette/FastAPI uses `SpooledTemporaryFile` behind the scenes, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804).

   ```py
   @app.post("/ping")
   def ping(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
       print("Hello")
       try:
           contents = file.file.read()
           res = cpu_bound_task(contents)
       finally:
           file.file.close()
       print("bye")
       return "pong"
   ```
2. Use FastAPI's (Starlette's) [`run_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/concurrency.py#L35) function from the `concurrency` module—as @tiangolo suggested [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1066#issuecomment-612940187)—which "will run the function in a separate thread to ensure that the main thread (where coroutines are run) does not get blocked" (see [here](https://bocadilloproject.github.io/guide/async.html#common-patterns)). As described by @tiangolo [here](https://gitter.im/tiangolo/fastapi?at=5ce550f675d9a575a625feb7), "`run_in_threadpool` is an `await`able function; the first parameter is a normal function, the following parameters are passed to that function directly. It supports both *sequence* arguments and *keyword* arguments".

   ```py
   from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool

   res = await run_in_threadpool(cpu_bound_task, contents)
   ```
3. Alternatively, use `asyncio`'s [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)—after obtaining the running `event loop` using [`asyncio.get_running_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop)—to run the task, which, in this case, you can `await` for it to complete and return the result(s), before moving on to the next line of code. Passing `None` to the *executor* argument, the *default* executor will be used; which is a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):

   ```py
   import asyncio

   loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
   res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, cpu_bound_task, contents)
   ```

   or, if you would like to [pass keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio-pass-keywords) instead, you could use a `lambda` expression (e.g., `lambda: cpu_bound_task(some_arg=contents)`), or, preferably, [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which is specifically recommended in the documentation for [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor):

   ```py
   import asyncio
   from functools import partial

   loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
   res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial(cpu_bound_task, some_arg=contents))
   ```

   In Python 3.9+, you could also use [`asyncio.to_thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) to asynchronously run a synchronous function in a separate thread—which, essentially, uses `await loop.run_in_executor(None, func_call)` under the hood, as can been seen in the [implementation of `asyncio.to_thread()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c5660ae96f2ab5732c68c301ce9a63009f432d93/Lib/asyncio/threads.py#L12). The `to_thread()` function takes the name of a blocking function to execute, as well as any arguments (`*args` and/or `**kwargs`) to the function, and then returns a coroutine that can be `await`ed. Example:

   ```
   import asyncio

   res = await asyncio.to_thread(cpu_bound_task, contents)
   ```

   **Note** that as explained in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804), passing `None` to the `executor` argument **does not** create a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` every time you call `await loop.run_in_executor(None, ...)`, but instead re-uses the *default* executor with the *default* number of worker threads (i.e., `min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)`). Thus, depending on the requirements of your application, that number might be quite low. In that case, you should rather use a custom [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor). For instance:

   ```py
   import asyncio
   import concurrent.futures

   loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
   with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
       res = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, cpu_bound_task, contents)
   ```

   I would strongly recommend having a look at the linked answer above to learn about the difference between using `run_in_threadpool()` and `run_in_executor()`, as well as how to create a re-usable custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` at the application startup, and adjust the number of maximum worker threads as needed.
4. `ThreadPoolExecutor` will successfully prevent the `event loop` from being blocked, but won't give you the **performance improvement** you would expect from running **code in parallel**; especially, when one needs to perform `CPU-bound` tasks, such as the ones described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#is-concurrency-better-than-parallelism) (e.g., audio or image processing, machine learning, and so on). It is thus preferable to **run CPU-bound tasks in a separate process**—using [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor), as shown below—which, again, you can integrate with `asyncio`, in order to `await` it to finish its work and return the result(s). As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15900366), it is important to protect the entry point of the program to avoid recursive spawning of subprocesses, etc. Basically, your code must be under [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

   ```py
   import concurrent.futures

   loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
   with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
       res = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, cpu_bound_task, contents)
   ```

   Again, I'd suggest having a look at the linked answer earlier on how to create a re-usable `ProcessPoolExecutor` at the application startup. You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862153/17865804) helpful as well.
5. Use **more [workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/)** to take advantage of multi-core CPUs, in order to run multiple processes in parallel and be able to serve more requests. For example, `uvicorn main:app --workers 4` (if you are using [Gunicorn as a process manager with Uvicorn workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/#gunicorn-with-uvicorn-workers), please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613757/17865804)). When using 1 worker, only one process is run. When using multiple workers, this will spawn multiple processes (all single threaded). Each process has a separate Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), as well as its own `event loop`, which runs in the main thread of each process and executes all tasks in its thread. That means, there is only one thread that can take a lock on the interpreter of each process; unless, of course, you employ additional threads, either outside or inside the `event loop`, e.g., when using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `loop.run_in_executor`, or defining endpoints/background tasks/`StreamingResponse`'s generators with normal `def` instead of `async def`, as well as when calling `UploadFile`'s methods (see the first two paragraphs of this answer for more details).

   **Note:** Each worker ["has its own things, variables and memory"](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/concepts/#memory-per-process). This means that `global` variables/objects, etc., won't be shared across the processes/workers. In this case, you should consider using a database storage, or  Key-Value stores (Caches), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699375/17865804). Additionally, note that "if you are consuming a large amount of memory in your code, **each process** will consume an equivalent amount of memory".
6. If you need to perform **heavy background computation** and you don't necessarily need it to be run by the same process (for example, you don't need to share memory, variables, etc), you might benefit from using other bigger tools like [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/), as described in [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#caveat).

Comment: In fact this was a trial to check why another call was running serial. The other function calls "UploadFile" and does an "await file.read()" and also runs serial. Moreover, this is run inside an amazon server product, after an api gateway from amazon, and hence all of the requests come from the same IP, since the user connects to amazon, and amazon server calls my api. The problem is that the operation with file is long, and if I have this serialized at the end I have timeouts because of Amazon limitation. I guess I will have to go for the last link you provided!

Comment: After loading the file (an image) I do some hard processing of the image and I upload the image to AWS server (there are S3 handlers). However, there aren't any other explicit awaits in the code.

Comment: To load the image I have: def myfunc(image: bytes = File(...)): Image.open(BytesIO(image)).convert('RGB'), but this now fails. Before it was: async def myfunc(image: UploadFile = File(...)): Image.open(BytesIO(await image.read())).convert('RGB') How should it be without async and wait?

Comment: computation task means CPU-intensive load. In CPython, threads don't make noticeable boosts for CPU tasks because of GIL which allows only one thread to be active at the moment. Thus, neither the `def` route nor `run_in_threadpool` will help here.

Comment: @zhanymkanov Thanks for the comment. I am aware of Python's GIL, and thus, I am planning on extending the above answer soon to provide further solutions using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Option 1 mentioned above (i.e., increasing the number of `workers`) is already one solution to this problem. Regardless, running such tasks in an external threadpool that is then awaited, instead of being called directly - although not offering a true parallelism - is better than nothing, as such tasks would otherwise block the entire server.

Comment: First of all thank you! But could you please elaborate on that `FastAPI can read the bytes of a file for you`?

Comment: @bravmi You are welcome. The relevant section above has been updated; hopefully, it is now more clear. For more details, please have a look at the links provided above.

Comment: @chris When await is used will the code error out if the next step needs output the awaited operation? What does python execute next to avoid blocking when it encounters await? is it the next line in the code?

Comment: @GeorgeOfTheRF I've just posted an [answer to your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743908/17865804). Please have a look.

Comment: Finally I found this great answer!!!

Comment: @Chris just for clarity to be sure. If I use more N workers, then async routes will have N event loops, which can be blocked, right? Another question, is ThreadPoolExecutor shared between multiple workers on each worker has it's own ThreadPoolExecutor for non-async route? Thanks for clarification!

Comment: It's a pitty that such a great answer cannot be found in the fastAPI official document, which does  not describe these clearly. It would save a lot of time for a lot of people

Comment: @iwtu The answer above has been updated with the relevant details. Please have a look (under the section where the "multiple workers" option is discussed).

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :**
> *<sub>" ... What's the problem? "</sub>*

**A :**
The FastAPI documentation is explicit to say the framework uses in-process tasks ( as inherited from *[Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/)* ).

That, by itself, means, that all such task compete to receive ( from time to time ) the Python Interpreter GIL-lock - being efficiently a MUTEX-terrorising Global Interpreter Lock, which in effect re-`[SERIAL]`-ises any and all amounts of Python Interpreter in-process threads
 to work as *one-and-**only-one-WORKS**-while-all-others-stay-waiting*...

On fine-grain scale, you see the result -- if spawning another handler for the second ( manually initiated from a second FireFox-tab ) arriving http-request actually takes longer than a sleep has taken, the result of GIL-lock interleaved `~ 100 [ms]` time-quanta round-robin ( all-wait-one-can-work `~ 100 [ms]` before each next round of GIL-lock release-acquire-roulette takes place ) Python Interpreter internal work does not show more details, you may use more details ( depending on O/S type or version ) from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=thread_id#time.pthread_getcpuclockid) to see more [in-thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) LoD, like this inside the async-decorated code being performed :

```py
import time
import threading
from   fastapi import FastAPI, Request

TEMPLATE = "INF[{0:_>20d}]: t_id( {1: >20d} ):: {2:}"

print( TEMPLATE.format( time.perf_counter_ns(),
                        threading.get_ident(),
                       "Python Interpreter __main__ was started ..."
                        )
...
@app.get("/ping")
async def ping( request: Request ):
        """                                __doc__
        [DOC-ME]
        ping( Request ):  a mock-up AS-IS function to yield
                          a CLI/GUI self-evidence of the order-of-execution
        RETURNS:          a JSON-alike decorated dict

        [TEST-ME]         ...
        """
        print( TEMPLATE.format( time.perf_counter_ns(),
                                threading.get_ident(),
                               "Hello..."
                                )
        #------------------------------------------------- actual blocking work
        time.sleep( 5 )
        #------------------------------------------------- actual blocking work
        print( TEMPLATE.format( time.perf_counter_ns(),
                                threading.get_ident(),
                               "...bye"
                                )
        return { "ping": "pong!" }
```

Last, but not least, do not hesitate to read more about all [other sharks](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/) threads-based code may suffer from ... or even cause ... behind the curtains ...

### Ad Memorandum

A mixture of GIL-lock, thread-based pools, asynchronous decorators, blocking and event-handling -- a sure mix to uncertainties & HWY2HELL ;o)